# My NSArray is now NSMutableArray and it makes my app crash

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I was using an `NSArray` for display of data in my DetailViewController. Now I have changed it to a `NSMutableArray`, and it crashes when it reach `viewWillAppear` when I push to the DetailViewController. What can cause this?

Sent from viewController to DetailViewController:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {


if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"DetailSegue"]) {

    NSIndexPath *selectedRowIndex = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    WinesDetailViewController *winesdetailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];

    winesdetailViewController.detailsDataSource = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortedWines,nil];
    winesdetailViewController.detailIndex = selectedRowIndex.row;
}
```

}

Recieved:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *detailsDataSource;
@property int detailIndex;
```

viewWillAppear:

```
if ([[[detailsDataSource objectAtIndex: detailIndex] valueForKey:@"Rate"] isEqual:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]])  {

    ratingImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ratingButtonOne@2x.png"];
}

flagImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[detailsDataSource objectAtIndex: detailIndex] valueForKey:@"Flag"]];
```

This is part of what is displayed in log:

`-[__NSArrayI isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6d2ee20
2012-08-15 00:00:16.860 Rødvinsguiden test[4240:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI isEqualToString:]: unrecognized     selector sent to instance 0x6d2ee20'`

Comment: If you have a crash, post the backtrace.   If you have an object that is suspected cause of the crash, post how the object is created.

Comment: Short answer is: no, you access elements in NSMutableArrays exactly the same as in an NSArray. That's not your problem here. You have a memory or object management issue here.

Comment: Everything was working fine until I made a MutableArray from detailsDataSource, what could cause this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`winesdetailViewController.detailsDataSource` is a `NSMutableArray` containing a `NSArray`. I'm guessing previously your array contained a number of strings and that you actually want to create it using:

```
winesdetailViewController.detailsDataSource = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:sortedWines];
```

Comment: Thanks, was starting to get really worryed

Answer (score 1):

NSMutableArray is a subclass of NSArray which means any method from NSArray can be used exactly the same way for NSMutableArray. Can you please post the crash log or the trace from the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use `[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:otherArray]`

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: @Dustin If I needed more clarification on that author's post I would have used a comment.

Comment: This answer was flagged as "low quality" in review. That's an autocomment.